# UIAlertController does not turn all elements in the background to B/W

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

EDIT: Repository with my solution: [UIAlertControllerDimmed](https://github.com/Janscho/UIAlertControllerDimmed)

---

After showing UIAlertController, most of the background gets 'dimmed' and turns black and white. Some elements get darker, but don't turn B/W.

These elements are (from top to bottom on the screenshot):

- UIImageView inside UINavigationItem
- UIButton with red background color and white image
- UIImageView inside UITabBarItem

[image: with alert controller]

I couldn't find anything related to this topic. What do I have to change to also get these items dimmed?

Here is the without the UIAlertController:

[image: without alert controller]]

Comment: Are you sure these ui elements don't dim? It might just appear that way because they are colored. Try checking the RGB values using an eyedropper tool (I suggest https://support.apple.com/guide/digital-color-meter/welcome/mac)

Comment: @toddg I might have worded that badly. Yes, they turn a little bit darker, but it does not change to black and white like the other elements. I edited my title.

Comment: @toddg That is wrong, several of the elements in the background have colors that aren't grayscale (like the notification bubble above the 'Chat' menu item, which is red). The message views in the back are also red.

Comment: Ok, the fact that one of your chat bubbles changes from red can’t be inferred from your question. I stand by my comment that standard behavior of `UIAlertController` is to apply a transparent black mask.

Comment: @toddg What's your point? Above is the proof that it does more than that. I don't know what else it does, and I'd be happy to know. All I can tell you is that I'm simply presenting the `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

In order to have a more flexible solution I decided to create a subclass of `UIAlertController` which captures a screenshot, turns it to grayscale colors and inserts it behind the `UIAlertController` when it gets presented. This way it works without having to do any additional work, and you don't need to implement fade animations for every single element that does not turn to grayscale colors by default.

[Github repo: UIAlertControllerDimmed](https://github.com/Janscho/UIAlertControllerDimmed)

Answer (score 4):

I think what's going on here is that you're setting the `tintColor` of some of the elements and you get different behavior for `tintColor` than you do for `backgroundColor` or `textColor` (or the colors in an image).

> When an alert or action sheet appears, iOS 7 automatically dims the
>   tint color of the views behind it. To respond to this color change, a
>   custom view subclass that uses tintColor in its rendering should
>   override tintColorDidChange to refresh the rendering when appropriate.

For example, I created a simple app that displays an alert controller. I set the left button tint color to clear color and the text color to blue:

[image]

I set the right button tint color to system green color:

[image]

When I run the app and present the alert controller it looks like this

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

In order to get the behavior you're looking for, you'll need to follow the advice in @Alexander's answer. You'll need to create grayscale versions of the four images on the screen and animate the transition to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a helper function to animate the color change

```
fileprivate func dimElements(highlight: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.sendButton.backgroundColor = highlight ? .red : .gray
    }
}
```

and then call it when presenting/dismissing the alert.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Oops!", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: {_ in self.dimElements(highlight: true) })
alert.addAction(okAction)
self.dimElements(highlight: false)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am wondering why it doesn't work by itself with these elements. It works for the others without doing anything else (like the notification bubble above the 'Chat' menu item).